# Pushing swapped data back into memory in Redis

Tags: redis

I have a redis instance with a fair amount of data that has been swapped to disk. I've managed to free a bunch of memory from the machine, so everything swapped should fit into memory without any problems now. What is the best strategy for doing this to minimize performance issues or downtime? Naively, I would guess that reading through all the keys would push everything into memory. Seems like I could also dump the db to disk, kill the redis-server, and turn it back on. Is there a better way, either with redis or with memory tools in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the OS has paged out a part of Redis memory (i.e. you do not use the deprecated virtual memory feature of old Redis versions), the easiest way to enforce all data to be accessed is simply to dump the database (by using BGSAVE).

While dumping the database, all the keys and their content will be accessed by the background process, so the OS will have to page the corresponding memory in. A lot of I/Os will be generated due to swapping activity, but they will block only the background thread. There will be little impact on the main Redis process serving your traffic (provided it does not use AOF).

You do not have to restart Redis, a simple background save should be enough.

Comment: Ok, this is reassuring. I am still a bit confused, because looking at the output of `smaps` for the redis process in question (per antirez's latency page on redis.io) I see a bunch of data swapped. `vmstat` does not show any swap activity, however. Does linux clean this swapped memory lazily, so that it might exist in both memory and in swapped space?

Comment: Yes the swapped data are actually cached. See http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=314